# Inserting cart data to database not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

**cart controller**

```
public function order()
{
    $cartContentString = serialize($this->cart->contents());
    $data = unserialize($cartContentString);

    $this->Product_Model->add_order($data);
}
```

**Product_Model**

```
public function add_order($data)
{
    $insert =$this->db->insert('cart',$data);
    return $insert;
    redirect('products');       
}
```

Comment: can you add the php msg error ?

Comment: How does it not work? I see at least one issue with your code.

Comment: No php msg error in code but data can,t insert in table plz help me

Comment: You need to tells us a little more about how your code is not working.  Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code.

The most glaringly obvious is this;

```
return $insert; // Nothing will be executed after this line
redirect('products');
```

Nothing will be executed after the return statement. It will return the value of your DB insert to whatever calls `add_order()` (in this case the cart controller) and not execute `redirect('products')`.

But in the first method, `order()`, I don't know why you would `serialize` the data on one line and `unserialize` it on the next - you just get what you had before.

```
$this->Product_Model->add_order($this->cart->contents());
```

would have the same effect as the entire first method.

Comment: Thanks for answering..i am beginner in codeigniter i don't know complete functionality of codeigniter framework if you can send me code of insert data of cart into database i am very thankful for you

Comment: This isn't restricted to codeigniter. This is the case in PHP in general.

Comment: i can use your method `$this->Product_Model->add_order($this->cart->contents());`but in this case it gave  syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: That's a syntax error on the previous line. There's either no end of line marker `;`, or no opening bracket on the method.

Comment: Thanks  i can remove the error but it also can,t work